# Django-selectable and autocomplete: Autocomplete does not work. Should I add my own JS?

Tags: jquery, python, django, autocomplete, django-select-related

I'm trying to use Django selectable on django.auth User. It returs JSON with users on `selectable/organiser_app-userlookup/`, but no autocomplete appears in input.

I've registered `selectable` in `INSTALLED_APPS`:

```
    INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ...
    'selectable',
    )
```

Also added to `url.py` in base project urls:

```
    url(r'^selectable/', include('selectable.urls')),
```

My `lookup.py` is:

```
     #UserLookup
class UserLookup(ModelLookup):
    model = User
    search_fields = ('first_name__icontains', 'last_name_icontains', 'email_icontains')

def get_item_value(self, item):
    # Display for currently selected item
    return item.username

def get_item_label(self, item):
    # Display for choice listings
    return u"%s (%s)" % (item.username, item.get_full_name())

registry.register(UserLookup)
```

and lookup form:

```
    class UserLookupForm(forms.Form):
user_input = forms.CharField(
    label='Type user name, last name or email',
    widget=selectable.AutoCompleteWidget(lookup_class=UserLookup),
    required=False,
)
```

My template has just input from form and it's rendered as:

```
<form>
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label" for="id_user_input">
    Type user name, last name or email</label>
<div class="col-sm-6 coll-sm-offset-3">
    <input class="form-control" 
    data-selectable-allow-new="false" 
    data-selectable-type="text" 
    data-selectable-url="/selectable/organiser_app-userlookup/"   
    id="id_user_input" 
    name="user_input" 
    placeholder="Type user name, last name or email" title="" 
    type="text" />
</div></div>
<p class="btn btn-default" role="button" 
id="button_add">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></span>
</p>
</form>
```

When I look at url `selectable/organiser_app-userlookup/` I get JSON with users, so it seems like Django-selectble works. How should I use autocomplete now? Should I add some JQuery source to my template? I just don't understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, the problem was there was no js script that handles all autocomplete events.

Just need to pass JS to the template template.
Specify somewhere in code:

```
{{ form.media.js }}
```

It will render to:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/selectable/js/jquery.dj.selectable.js?v=0.9.0"></script>
```

This helped for me.

I just don't know why there is nothing about this mentioned in the docs.